# Embed a video using Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to use Google Scripting to embed videos I have stored on my Google Drive into HTML. Here's the code I'm using to generate the HTML:

```
function GenerateTables() {
    var folderz = DocsList.getFolder('SharedVideos');
    var contents = folderz.getFiles().sort(function(a,b) {return b.getDateCreated()-a.getDateCreated()});
    var file;
    var name;
    var date;
    var url;
    var dateModified;
    var folder;

    var textOutput = "<table>";
    textOutput += "<tr><th>File Name</th><th>Create Date</th><th>Modified Date</th></tr>"
    for (var i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) { 
        file = contents[i];
        folder = file.getParents()[0];
        name = file.getName();
        url = "https://docs.google.com/file/d/" +file.getId()+"/preview";

        date = Utilities.formatDate(file.getDateCreated(), 'GMT-6', 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aaa');
        dateModified = Utilities.formatDate(file.getLastUpdated(), 'GMT-6', 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aaa');
        textOutput += "<tr><td>" +name + "</td><td>" + date + "</td><td>" + dateModified + "</td></tr>";
        textOutput += "<tr><td colspan='3'>";
        textOutput += "<iframe src='"+url+"' height='385' width='640'></iframe>";
        textOutput += "</td></tr>";
  }
  textOutput +="</table>";
  return textOutput;
}


function doGet() {
    var text = GenerateTables();
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(text);
}
```

The iframe is being converted to

```
<iframe data-caja-src='[the correct URL]' height="385" width="640"></iframe>
```

I was hoping it would be a simple process, but the more I got looking into it, the more complicated it seemed to be. Is there an easier way to do what I'm trying to do? I don't have much experience using Caja, but maybe there's a simple way to embed a video using Caja, I just couldn't get anything to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not yet a way to embed videos inside HtmlService. I think there's a feature request for it on the issue tracker, but regardless it's something we know about.